# Modulus division to get multiples of 10

Tags: java, modulus

I'm currently doing a practice where I'm given a non-negative number "num", and return true if num is within 2 of a multiple of 10.

I have the idea of an if statement which would include the below, but a more working / similar version;

```
if (num-2 >= (num % 10 == 0) <= num+2);
```

Seems like I'm trying to create a variable with all multiples of 10, however this seems a bit overkill. I feel it's basic arithmetic with something like num-2 >= x <= num+2, where x is a multiple of 10, but what is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for numbers that end in 0,1,2,8 or 9, which means

```
if (num % 10 <= 2 || num % 10 >= 8)
```

Comment: Did you consider negatives? Any negative number will return true for this condition.

Comment: @Michael The question says `I'm given a non-negative number "num"`

Comment: So it does. Still, worth the disclaimer.

Comment: @Michael: The next thing then will be a disclaimer for `num` being a floating point type. This looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Pretty much answers the question. Thank you very much Eran for answering it, worked with flying colours. :)